# When trying to create a question, if a new tag is suggested, it unticks the community wiki box

Tags: bug, status-completed

To reproduce:

1. Start a new question
2. Tick the community wiki box
3. Fill in question and answer
4. Make up a new tag
5. Submit the question

The page comes back complaining about not being able to create the tag due to <150 rep on this site.

What you probably wont notice (not least because of the big question preview separating the two) is that the community wiki box has become unticked.

(It'd also be helpful if the question submit wasn't necessary to find this out - the tag lookup is capable of telling if it's a new tag, so it should have warned before the submit also.)

This occurred on the main webapps site, and I've just reproduced it here.

Comment: This might well be a problem on all sites.

Comment: This is a problem on all sites - I've just repeated it on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have low enough reputation, otherwise I would have tested there also.

Comment: Of course, if Stack Exchange was Open Source, I could go a step further: fix it, and submit a patch.

Comment: it's easy to test on Meta - just miss off one of the required tags.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed - this will be deployed this evening.